# How to change camera access?

Tags: camera

I have a inbuilt camera and I want to change camera access for Ubuntu! In Windows I can simply go to privacy > Camera and turn access off! but How to do it in Ubuntu?

**Edit :** I found a way to disable camera *temporally*

To disable camera temporally -  `sudo modprobe -r uvcvideo`

To enable it - `sudo modprobe uvcvideo`

Comment: Do you mean restricting camera access for all apps or for certain apps only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done via the *Applications* tab in "Settings" for applications that have specifically requested permission to access the camera. Chromium is a good example of this:

[image: Chromium Permissions]

However, a lot of applications that can use the camera, such as OBS Studio, do not provide an option that is available through Settings. Instead, you need to disable the camera globally via dconf Editor:

[image: dconf Editor]

If you do not already have dconf Editor on your system, you can install it via Terminal like this:

```
sudo apt install dconf-editor
```

Hope this gives you what you need.

Comment: Yes this helped me but i don't see a option like **Applications** in Settings! I'm using **Ubuntu 18.04 LTS**